# How to detect table that have overflow when reach bottom [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create UI like infinite scroll inside this table element with overflow style. So I can dynamically adding row when reach bottom table.

Can we do it? I'll try many script but still can't get the end of table overflow.

```
$('#table').on('scroll', function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        alert('end reached');
    }       
})
```

Thanks in advance.
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to set the scroll handler on `tbody` instead of `table`.

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/ocfyu8mL/