# Bootstrap table overflow event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Based on my previous question:
[How to detect table that have overflow when reach bottom [jQuery]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691496/how-to-detect-table-that-have-overflow-when-reach-bottom-jquery)

I've become crazy to redesign UI for table with overflow style (bad at front-end). This bootstrap example give me the good UI but I hadn't found element to detect the scroll event when reach bottom row.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrefadila/vbcwbz5m/2/

```
$('.fixed-table-body').on('scroll', function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        alert('end reached');
    }
})
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I believe is the binding for the scroll event, as the element with the class `.fixed-table-body`, doesn't exist until the bootstrap table has finished rendering.

To get round this, bind the scroll event when the post header event for the bootstrap table fires.

```
$("table").on("post-header.bs.table",function() {
    $("#console").append("<div>hello</div>");

    $('.fixed-table-body').unbind().on("scroll", function () {
        $("#console").append("<div>hello</div>");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v0c4rtnf/9/

Comment: Can you tell me how do you know `post-header.bs.table` element? Thanks anyway master!

Comment: @andrefadila looking on the events in the documentation at http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#events I originally thought it might be the post-body.bs.table event, but turns out the header is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

try with this below jquery it will help you to.

```
$("table").on("post-header.bs.table",function() {
$('.fixed-table-body').on("scroll", function () {
    if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()>=$(this)[0].scrollHeight)
    {
      alert('end reached');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I know this is the right code after @Valeklosse give the idea first. Thanks anyway.